# What's the difference between rectangular tea bags and pyramid tea bags?

Tags: tea

Does the difference in shape between pyramid and regular rectangular tea bags have any practical consequences? Perhaps a difference in preparation method, or in the resulting tea?

Comment: Pure marketing, designed to extract more money from your wallet, not flavour from the tea. If you think a pyramid brews better, just leave your regular tea bag in a little longer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pyramid teabag allows for more effective and faster extraction. This is because the tea bag retains its 3 dimensional shape, so there is plenty of space for the tea leaves, and more of their surface area is exposed for extraction.

A conventional teabag actually becomes smaller, and there is less space and the tea leaves are pressed onto each other, creating a compressed little ball of tea. I think whoever invented the pyramid teabag had that in mind. I am not suggesting that the world was desperate for it though ;)